# How to validate HTML form and call JS function through the same button? If not, how to set it up properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to use required and patterns in my HTML form. The submit button for the form has a function attached to it on document ready that hides the new-guest div and shows the qr-generated div. This function is attached to all page-show buttons. There is also a function that is attached to the form on submit that processes the info in the form. Currently, when I click the submit button, it hides the new-guest div, despite the inputs not being filled out or valid. I feel like there's a minimal change I can make before I write more specific functions for this form. Any advice on how I can proceed?

```
<div class="container p-4 view" id="new-guest">
    <!-- when making a form, always start with form class, form-floating is a bootstrap class -->
    <form class="form-floating" method="post" id="infoform">
      <!-- each form-floating div holds a label and the input you want to take in -->
      <div class="form-floating">
        <!-- type is self explanatory, form-control is bootstrap class, placeholder is for the animation to work, required is self explanatory -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="lionel" required><br><br>
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="messi" required><br><br>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]{10}" placeholder="idk"
          required>
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        <small>Format: 1234567890</small><br><br>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" page-show="qr-generated" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

```
//function attached to buttons to change div currently viewable
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function (e) {
        showView("home");
        function showView(viewName) {
          $('.view').hide();
          $('#' + viewName).show();
        }
        $('[page-show]').click(function (e) {
          var viewName = $(this).attr('page-show');
          showView(viewName);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

```
async function submitForm(e) {
        // Get form values
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
....
}
var form = document.getElementById("infoform");
form.addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
```

Comment: _"Currently, when I click the submit button, it hides the new-guest div"_ - but that was already hidden on page load, you said? When did it become visible again? Please present a proper [mre] of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate the HTML form and call a JavaScript function through the same button, you can modify your code as follows:

1. Add the onsubmit attribute to the  element and set it to return false;. This will prevent the form from being submitted automatically when the button is clicked.

```html
  <form class="form-floating" method="post" id="infoform" onsubmit="return false;">
```

2. Modify the submitForm function to include the form validation logic. If the form is valid, you can then call the desired JavaScript function.

```html
async function submitForm() {
  // Get form values
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;

  // Perform form validation
  if (firstName === "" || lastName === "" || phoneNumber === "") {
    // Display error message or perform any necessary validation logic
    alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    return;
  }

  // Call your JavaScript function
  yourFunctionName();

  // Optionally, you can submit the form programmatically
  // document.getElementById("infoform").submit();
}
```

3. Update the button element to call the submitForm function when clicked.

```html
<button type="submit" page-show="qr-generated" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

With these changes, when the "Submit" button is clicked, the submitForm function will be called. It will perform form validation and call your desired JavaScript function if the form is valid. If the form is invalid, it will display an error message or perform any other validation logic as needed.